# Receive new props in _app.js (nextjs)?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to say, if I dispatch a action in _app's componentDidMount, coul I receive the new props for this action in _app ? and if Yes, how ? thanks

```
import React from 'react'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import App, {Container} from 'next/app'
import withRedux from 'next-redux-wrapper'
import withReduxSaga from 'next-redux-saga'
import configureStore from './configure-store'

class ExampleApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps({Component, ctx}) {
    let pageProps = {}
     //This a action with redux-saga
     ctx.store.dispatch(doSomething)

    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
      pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
    }

    return {pageProps}
  }

  render() {
    const {Component, pageProps, store} = this.props
    return (
      <Container>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Provider>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}

export default withRedux(configureStore)(withReduxSaga(ExampleApp))
```

In this code, How and where can I recover result of my action ?

my configureStore :

```
import reducers from "./services/reducers";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";
import IndexSaga from "./services/sagas";

export const configureStore = (preloadedState, { isServer, req = null }) => {
  const composeEnhancers =
    (typeof window !== "undefined" &&
      window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__) ||
    compose;
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

  const store = createStore(
    reducers,
    preloadedState,
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware))
  );

  if (req || !isServer) {
    store.sagaTask = sagaMiddleware.run(IndexSaga);
  }
  return store;
};
```

Comment: This is the main concept of redux.  Please read docs.

Comment: I've know redux, but I learn nextjs and I want to use redux with and it's work differently...

Comment: concept the same. You dispatch an action, store your result in store and then get is from store.

Comment: I think, you don't know what you are saying. Do you know nextjs? you know how it's work ?

Comment: Yes, I know what i'm talking about. Redux is not related to any framework! Just check `next-redux-wrapper`

Comment: Look my edit please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then just get back your store and bring some updated value from there.

```
....
const store = configureStore.getState();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, my application use the class components. I can't use the hooks haha.

Comment: SSR is only for rendering the initial state, after the first render we have a normal client side redux app.

Comment: and you have already your store in `const {Component, pageProps, store} = this.props`. store variable should included updated store.